# Responsive navbar not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Trying to get my Bootstrap responsive nav-bar/header to work. But nothing happens when I  click the icon  to show the menu when I'm in mobile sized screen.

To explain it a bit better, I want to do a navbar kinda like this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

And here's my code:

```
 <!-- HEADER/NAVBAR -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Images\O3_square_mid.gif"></a>
   </div>

   <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Analysstatus</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Aktiva kunder</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </nav>
  <!--HEADER/NAVBAR -->
```

The only javascript im using is
src="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

Not sure if I need jquery but ive tried with and without it and still nothing happens.

Comment: All of the Javascript plugins in Bootstrap require JQuery to work. [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)
I found it helpful to begin with their starter template, which includes a link to JQuery.
[Bootstrap Template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but its the template I already used and I tried both with and without the jQuery, will keep in mind that I need jQuery for these kind of things though, even if it takes the page forever to load...

Comment: Are you including the file inline or linking to a hosted repo? Jquery should not slow your load time down by too much. Are you grabbing the .min version of the file?

Comment: linking to a hosted repo I guess, as that template suggests

Comment: Try including it in your Rails build. I am not exactly sure how you do it in Rails but should include it in your dependencies and if you are running the application in development mode it should decrease the load time for JQuery.
Here is a link to a Ruby Gem for [Bootstrap](https://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails). It should include Jquery.

Comment: Thanks but I'm only using html/css/js/php :) Will try and look into that problem after I've solved my main problem with this collapsable navbar..

Comment: Actually, not using a hosted repo solved my initial problem, thanks for taking your time with me. Wish you had answered so I could accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong `data-target` for the navbar collapse. 
Change the toggle button to:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

The docs reference `navbar-ex1-collapse` as the target, but this is only relevant for the docs.

Demo: http://bootply.com/90771

Comment: Tried this, still doesen't work as intended. Problem still the same, when I make my screen smaller or view on device with smaller screen I get the button that is supposed to collapse into a menu but when I click it nothing happens..

Comment: Are you saying that your code doesn't work or the Bootply doesn't work on smaller screen? Also, what browser/device are you using?

Answer (score 1):

*Adding my comment as an answer:*
When using Rails or another framework that loads plugins and dependencies make sure the issue is not with your project's dependency resolution. Include bootstrap in your plugin dependencies. For example, in Ruby you want to install the following:

```
gem install twitter-bootstrap-rails
```

This will ensure that Bootstrap works as expected.